# What is 100% in calc function

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, calc

Within the  css `calc()` function, what does `100%` refer to and what is the equivalent code in JavaScript?

```
#div1 {
   width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xoufnm6v/

Comment: It's the same 100% as if you wrote it without the calc function.

Comment: The example on that page doesn't seem great - if you change `width: calc(100% - 100px)` to `right: 50px` to achieve the same thing as being described, the yellow box ends up narrower - ie they haven't come up with an entirely accurate demo.

Comment: @JamesThorpe actually it *is* accurate. Without `box-sizing` specified, the `width` here is the *inner* width of the element - that is the width with the `padding` and `border` factored out. `left` and `right` ignore the `border` and `padding` completely, thus making the element 12px larger when both `left` and `right` are applied (2 * 5px padding + 2* 1px border)

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Indeed - but I meant accurate as regards the wording.  There _isn't_ a _"50px gap between both sides of the div and the edges of the window"_

Comment: Thank You all for your quick answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

100% refers to 100% of the width of the parent element. This calculation gives the current element a width 100 pixels narrower than it's parent.

Answer (score 4):

> what is 100% means

It is the percentage of the width of the parent. In this case it refers to 100% width of the parent element.

> what is the equivalent in javascript

Assuming you meant what it `100%-75` would be implemented in javascript/jquery

```
$(window).on("resize",function(){
   $('#element').css("width", ( $('#element').parent().width()-75 ) + "px");
});
```

or simply this

```
$('#element').css("width","calc(100% - 75px)");
```

simple javascript equivalent would be

```
element.style.cssText = "width: calc(100% - 75px);"
```

Comment: That's entirely jQuery, not JavaScript. jQuery isn't tagged here.

Answer (score 1):

100% refers to a percentage of the width of the containing element. So, 100% means the same width as the container.

In the referenced example `<body>` is the containing element, so 100% refers to the width of the `<body>`. From that `calc()` subtracts 100 pixels to arrive at the rendered size.

The calculated width responds to changes in the width of the containing element; if you resize the page you will see the `<div>` respond accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The 100% is to do with the width property.

The width property sets the width of an element.

Note: The width property does not include padding, borders, or margins; it sets the width of the area inside the padding, border, and margin of the element!

The % operator defines the width as a percentage of the containing block. So in the example the 100% is 100% of the page body, less the width of the the padding, border, and margin of the div. Then the calculation subtracts a further 100px from that.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp

Comment: The question is about calc

Comment: The question is what does the 100% mean. I talk about the width because it's a percentage of the width. I will edit to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

`calc()` is a native CSS way to do simple math right in CSS as a replacement for any length value (or pretty much any number value). It has four simple math operators: add (+), subtract (-), multiply (*), and divide (/). Being able to do math in code is nice and a welcome addition to a language that is fairly number heavy.

But is it useful? I've strained my brain in the past trying to think of obviously useful cases. There definitely are some though.

This is the one basic example.

```css
div{
  background: green;
  width: 70%;
}
span{
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  background: red;
  display: block;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div> <span>calc(100% - 150px) </span></div>
```

When can't calculate `%` with other values, like `px`, `em`, `cm`, etc .Above example you can done in JavaScript, but calc() will help to calculate the value in CSS.

For further information please check in google or Please refer here https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/